# I could not be able to maintain session in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session

I have been stuck for several hours but could not be able to retrieve session attributes.In other words session is not maintained between requests from controller to views in spring mvc. My controller code is as follows:-

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
    public ModelAndView search(HttpSession session2) {

        session2.setAttribute("name","abhi");
        Session session=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        String hql = "SELECT E.firstName FROM User E";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List results = query.list();

        //System.out.println(results.get(1).getClass().getFields());
        HashMap model = new HashMap();
        model.put("users", results);
        return new ModelAndView("search", model);
    }
```

the code where i am retrieving the session attributes is as follows:-

search.jsp

```
<div id="user"></div>
Welcome <% request.getSession().getAttribute("name"); %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<select id="userlist" onchange="a()">
    <option>Select User</option>
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <option>${user}</option>
</c:forEach>
    </select>

<script>
    function a()
    {
    document.write('<form method="post" id="chat" action="/abhishekchat/hello" > <input type="text" name="chatbox" id="chatbox"/>' +'Enter the name of the person you want to chat with'
            +'<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />'+
            '<input type="submit"  value="Submit" />' +
            '</form>');
    }

    $



</script>
```

Please help..thanx in advance..:)

Comment: oops.. i made a silly mistake by writing <% instead of "<%=". I rectified it..

Comment: You are writing the dao queries in controller which is very bad programming